# MySQL search between columns

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have the table described below.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | date_from | date_to | start_from stop_to
--------------------------------------------------
  1   2013-10-12   2013-11-12    1        3
  2   2013-09-08   2013-09-20    2        1
  3   2013-06-04   2013-06-12    1        1
  4   2013-05-02   2013-05-15    2        3
  5   2013-04-11   2013-09-13    2        1
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to select the data between the dates and start_from and stop_from in the format I want.

Let's say I want to search between 2013-01-01 and 2013-12-31 and where start_from or stop_to is 1

The result of the select should be

```
2013-10-12 1
2013-09-20 1
2013-06-04 1
2013-06-12 1
2013-09-13 1
```

If start_from or stop_to is 2 the result should be

```
2013-09-08 2
2013-05-02 2
2013-04-11 2
```

If start_from or stop_to is 3 the result should be

```
2013-11-12 3
2013-05-15 3
```

I hope you'll get the logic

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Use a union of two selects in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT the_date,start_stop FROM (
    SELECT
        id
    ,   date_from as the_date
    ,   start_from as start_stop
    FROM my_table WHERE start_from=1
        UNION ALL
    SELECT
        id
    ,   date_to as the_date
    ,   stop_to as start_stop
    FROM my_table WHERE stop_to=1
    ORDER BY id
) tmp
```

The first query looks for rows matching the `start_from` condition, and pulling the `date_from` for that match; the second query looks for rows matching the `date_to` condition, and pulls the `date_to` into the result. The `UNION ALL` operator concatenates the results of the two queries.

Here is a [demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15188a/9).

Comment: this will work but I need to keep the order of the dates as I described above

Comment: @moemoe You can reorder by ID in the inner query then, and get rid of the ID in the outer query.